# Matlab Versus Python - Interpolation Errors with Matlab "scatteredInterpolant" versus Python's "Griddata" from scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy, interpolation

I'm currently trying to convert some Matlab code into Python. I'm running into an error that I suspect has to do with rounding, but am unsure about what is causing it.
Matlab:

```
deg2rad = pi/180;

% Finds good index points for lon/lat
good_clim_ins=find(~isnan(squeeze(S_clim(1,1,:,:))));

% Converts those values to Cartesian coordinates 
[X_woa, Y_woa, Z_woa] = sph2cart(lon_woam(good_clim_ins)*deg2rad, lat_woam(good_clim_ins)*deg2rad, 1);

AI = 1:length(X_woa(:));
AI = reshape(AI, size(X_woa));

xyz= [X_woa(:) Y_woa(:) Z_woa(:)];

% The good part, Matlab returns an scatteredInterpolant 'object'
F  = scatteredInterpolant(xyz, AI(:),'nearest');
[prof_x, prof_y, prof_z] = sph2cart(MITprof.prof_lon*deg2rad, MITprof.prof_lat*deg2rad, 1);
% returns array of indexes 
prof_clim_cell_index = F(prof_x, prof_y, prof_z);]
```

My translation into Python:

```
deg2rad = np.float64(np.pi/180.0)

% Finds good index points for lon/lat
subset = S_clim[0,0].flatten(order= 'F')
good_clim_ins = np.where(~np.isnan(subset))[0]

% Converts those values to Cartesian coordinates 
lon_woam = lon_woam.flatten(order='F').astype(np.float64)
lat_woam = lat_woam.flatten(order='F').astype(np.float64)
X_woa, Y_woa, Z_woa = sph2cart(lon_woam[good_clim_ins]*deg2rad, lat_woam[good_clim_ins]*deg2rad, 1.0)

AI = np.arange(0,X_woa.size).astype(np.float64)

xyz = np.column_stack((X_woa, Y_woa, Z_woa)).astype(np.float64)

MITprofs['prof_lon'] = MITprofs['prof_lon'].astype(np.float64)
MITprofs['prof_lat'] = MITprofs['prof_lat'].astype(np.float64)
prof_x, prof_y, prof_z = sph2cart(MITprofs['prof_lon']*deg2rad, MITprofs['prof_lat']*deg2rad, np.float64(1))
    
% The interpolation in Python:
prof_clim_cell_index = griddata(xyz, AI, (prof_x, prof_y, prof_z), method='nearest')

% sph2cart function:
def sph2cart(az, elev, r):      
    rcoselev = r * np.cos(elev)    
    x = rcoselev * np.cos(az)     
    y = rcoselev* np.sin(az)     
    z = r * np.sin(elev)      
return x, y, z
```

I converted everything to np.float64 to ensure precision. I loaded the "prof_clim_cell_index" variable from Matlab into Python. This is my code below to check for consistency between the two:

```
    % subtract 1 to account for indexing differences b/w Matlab and Python
    mat_contents['prof_clim_cell_index'] = mat_contents['prof_clim_cell_index'] - 1
    ticker = 0
    for a in np.arange(prof_clim_cell_index.size):
        if prof_clim_cell_index[a] != mat_contents['prof_clim_cell_index'][a]:
            if not (np.isnan(prof_clim_cell_index[a]) and np.isnan(mat_contents['prof_clim_cell_index'][a])):
                print(prof_clim_cell_index[a])
                print(mat_contents['prof_clim_cell_index'][a])
                print("{}".format(a))
                ticker = ticker + 1
                print("--------")

    raise Exception(ticker)
```

From this, I get 50 different values out of 32364. Here are some outputs from the terminal:

Python: 3935.0
Matlab: 4086
a: 29822

19427.0
19575
31320

35204.0
35105
31587

35103.0
35202
31656

35102.0
35201
31726

35101.0
35200
31770

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why I'm getting these different values from Python versus Matlab? I know that my inputs to both functions are the same since I checked them. The only discrepancies I can see are from the arrays that are returned from the sph2cart functions, which have some rounding error like so:
prof_x[a] = -0.45880608166106984
mat_contents['prof_x'][a] = -0.4588060816610699

Comment: In your Python code, what is sph2cart? Is that coming from a library?

Comment: @NickODell It's a function to convert spherical to Cartesian coordinates. I've added the function here:
 `def sph2cart(az, elev, r):

    rcoselev = r * np.cos(elev)
    x = rcoselev * np.cos(az)
    y = rcoselev* np.sin(az)
    z = r * np.sin(elev)

    return x, y, z `

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that code? The SO comment box breaks formatting.

Comment: @NickODell Got it! just added it!